# Changing the English Country names to German language using Locale

Tags: java, locale

I have this requirements that I need to convert the equivalent country codes to German language country name. I am using the Locale builder for my codes.

Here are my codes:

The first one I did is this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("GERMANY", "AT");
```

Generated output: `German (Austria)`

The second one:

```
Locale aLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("de").setRegion("AT").build();
```

Generated output: `German (Austria)`

What I need is to Convert the countryCode `"AT"` which is Austria to German Language, and it should generate `Österreich`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method [`getDisplayCountry()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayCountry(java.util.Locale)) of `Locale` can take a `Locale` argument for which language to try to display it in. For example:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("de", "AT");
System.out.println(locale.getDisplayCountry(locale));
```

prints for me

```
Österreich
```

If you want the whole locale's name, just use `getDisplayName()` with a parameter, instead of `getDisplayCountry()`.

This isn't guaranteed to work for every combination of locales. According to the docs:

> If the name returned cannot be localized according to [the provided `Locale` parameter] (say, we don't have a Japanese name for Croatia), this function falls back on the English name, and finally on the ISO code as a last-resort value.

Also note that the language code for German is `"de"`, not `"GERMANY"`.

Answer (score 2):

Java `Locale`s are not a translation service.  They are used to describe localized components, for instance you might have a `Map<Locale, String> austria` which would contain mappings from `en` to `"Austria"` and `de_AT` to `"Österreich"`.  More likely, you would use Resource Bundles to map `Locale`s to a number of translations that you could then use throughout your application.  Here's the [`ResourceBundle` tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html).

If you want to translate text to another language, you'll need to use some sort of translation service, like [Google's Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/).